# Linear time algorithm for finding the greatest common divisor

Tags: math

I have been doing some research and I have found some algorithms that have greater than `0(N)` runtime. 
I am curious if anybody is aware of a linear time algorithm for finding the greatest common divisor?

Comment: What is the meaning of `N` in this case? The number of (binary) digits of the largest number? Also, what is the domain? Most GCD algorithms use division somewhere, and division is `O(1)` for 64 bit integers, but at least `O(n)` for integers of arbitrary precision.

Comment: I found a O( (n log n)^2 ) algorithm. I also found another that I was unsure what the actual runtime was but was confident that it wasn't linear.

Comment: @ElianEbbing: Sorry, in this case I am only concerned with integers. N would be the largest integer.

Comment: @VanDarg - If `N` is just the value of the largest integer, then the runtime complexity is `O(log n)` even for the euclidean algorithm. This is much better than `O(n)`.

Comment: @ElianEbbing: If N were the value of the largest integer in an array from [0..N], would the runtime then be O(NLog(N))?
I am trying to solve a problem that involves sorting fractions in an array. If I was able to find a GCD in the array in O(N) time, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is, noone has found it yet; from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor);

> the best known deterministic algorithm is by Chor and Goldreich, which
>   (in the CRCW-PRAM model) can solve the problem in O(n/log n) time with
>   n1+ε processors.